# Where are official images and metadata of cave paintings housed?

Tags: sources, prehistory

I have seen a few cave paintings at the [British Museum](https://africanrockart.britishmuseum.org/) and a couple other museums, but not very many and only of specific types. I also saw [Lascaux](https://www.lascaux.fr/en/prepare-your-visit/visit-lascaux/international-centre-for-cave-art) (French International Center for Cave Art) which doesn't have anything online, and the [Bradshaw Foundation](http://www.bradshawfoundation.com/sitemap.php) which sounded like it would have a lot of pieces ("rock art archives" of many types), but the images are of low quality and they don't seem to be formalized / documented like a museum would have it, it is more a personal collection it seems.

In the same way that there are many places that host many *manuscripts*, I am wondering if there are any standard places that host images/records on cave paintings / rock art.

Comment: [This](http://archaeologydataservice.ac.uk/era/section/gallery.jsf) is more like what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This site has high quality reproductions of several French caves:
http://archeologie.culture.fr/fr
I do not think that there is any general worldwide catalog of cave art. You have to search by country and by cave name. The best internet videos of cave art are French (not surprisingly).